# Returning results from multiple functions in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, return

I am trying to return the results of 2 functions, but I am not succeeding.  I am doing the following:

```
var x = getFunctionResults1(items);
var y = getFunctionResults2(items);
return {x,y}
```

But getting this output:

```
[ { x: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    y: [ [Object] ] },
  { x: [ [Object], [Object] ], y: [ [Object] ] } ]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use an array as result object for two functions, like

```
return [getFunctionResults1(functionResults1), getFunctionResults2(functionResults2)];
```

or use an object for the parts with a key, like

```
return {
    result1: getFunctionResults1(functionResults1),
    result2: getFunctionResults2(functionResults2)]
};
```